# Is there a way to trigger/call some javascript function when LCP is done?

Tags: javascript

I just want to know if there's a thing we can do to know that when the LCP is loaded completely so we can call any functions we want?

Comment: What is "*the LCP*"?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you've done and where is the exact issue.

Comment: @Bergi LCP is Largest Contentful Paint, it's basically the most important thing in optimizing page score and even SEO. Part of google's web vitals.

Comment: @Mr.R this is just a wild idea and there's no real issue at the moment. I come to this because there are several websites that are using videos on their Hero section and that causes a high score of LCP which is not good. So I though if there's a trigger where we can know that the LCP is done, we can load the video. For now I'm using a setTimeout but that's just a temporary.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you want to show a video, and the user expects to be able to watch a video, loading that just takes some time and it's ok. The idea of further delaying the video loading is weird, it just means the user will wait even longer until they can watch the video, which will neither increase user experience nor your SEO score.